# cannot access url string something missing on my code?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, url, vhosts

I have a problem with apache giving me a "not found" error.

scenario:

I have a url of the form --> 10.17.10.19/webapps/api/index.php?url=auth

I want to rewrite the url in the form --> 10.17.10.19/webapps/api/auth

im Using Ubuntu 20.04 apache2

vhost:

```
      <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

apache.conf

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes
# FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Please help me to correct the condition to recognize the parameter

Comment: i already enable aen2mod rewrite but still not works

Comment: Where is that distributed configuration file (".htaccess") located?

Comment: /var/www/html/webapps/api/.htaccess

Comment: Why the discrepancy between `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/` and `<Directory /var/www/>`?

Comment: document root for landing page and directory is when we set rule right? two different things

Comment: Sure. What I meant is why the different paths? What files are contained in `/var/www/`? I ask because I have never used such a setup, I am unsure if that is even possible.

Comment: i see then i need to remove that in directory so i just use <Directory> rules </Directory>
no need to attach more path

Comment: the url 10.17.10.19/webapps/api/index.php?url=auth working fine but when access through 10.17.10.19/webapp/api/auth error: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: i got this error on my error log
[Sat Oct 22 16:55:23.095946 2022] [core:alert] [pid 315095] [client 10.16.30.51:50474] /var/www/html/webapps/api/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps >
[Sat Oct 22 16:55:31.766145 2022] [core:alert] [pid 315097] [client 10.16.30.51:50473] /var/www/html/webapps/api/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps >
[Sat Oct 22 16:58:21.810250 2022] [core:alert] [pid 315095] [client 10.16.30.51:53853] /var/www/html/webapps/api/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps >

Comment: its working now by enable a2enmod headers thanks sir!

Comment: You nowhere show any usage of the `Header` directive in the lines you posted.

Comment: The `<Directory ...>` directive should have a path, usually it is the path of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Sometimes you want different settings for folder inside that location, then you add additional `Directory` directives for each such path.

Comment: i not using any header but log showing invalid header

Comment: That is a strange thing, then, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer
i need to enable header so the htaccess can work

```
ae2enmod header
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/

Comment: Can you [edit] to elaborate on what exactly you did to solve the problem? This can help future people who run into the same problem and see this post.

Comment: sorry guys
i edited the answer